# Add children to a dynamically added swf before adding to stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

as the title states, I am trying to add children to a dynamically added swf file, using AS3, before I add it to stage, is this possible?

Here is the code I have thus far,

AS3:

```
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(glo.bal.base_url+"videos/vid_1.swf");
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler_one);
mLoader.load(mRequest);

function onCompleteHandler_one(loadEvent:Event)
{
    //Here I would like to add a child to the swf file before I append it to stage
    video_container.addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

Inside the `vid_1` swf there is a movie clip called `box_one`, I would like to append a image to `box_one`, and only have the swf added to stage after the image file has been added to `box_one`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys, thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(glo.bal.base_url+"videos/vid_1.swf");
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler_one);
mLoader.load(mRequest);

function onCompleteHandler_one(loadEvent:Event)
{
    var loadedClip:MovieClip = loadEvent.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
    loadedClip.addChild(some_other_clip);
    loadedClip.someExistingChild.addChild(some_other_clip_2); // Only do this obviously if you're sure of the specifically named child of your load clip existing and in the right scope

    //This is specifically how you'd do this in your code
    loadedClip.box_one.addChild(somethingElse);
    stage.addChild(loadedClip);
}
```

Just to be safe, you might wanna wrap that in some error checking code:

```
if(loadedClip && loadedClip.box_one){
    loadedClip.box_one.addChild(somethingElse);
}
```

So yeah it's possible.

Comment: it should be `loadedClip['box_one']` unless mc is dynamic class.
And it will work only when `vid_1.swf` fla file is not extending some custom class.

Comment: When I run it I get this error... `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` , any ideas?

Comment: On which line of code? I'll test it today if I get the chance but I just did the modifications off the top of my head. Also @ Jevgenij I disagree. It doesn't need to be a dynamic class in order to access a pre-existing object within the display list.